# SBT to Maven Converter

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

Since most IDEs are only able to import Maven projects, I'd like to generate a POM.xml from an SBT managed project, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You should probably add a maven tag to this Q.

Comment: Another reason to generate POMs sometimes is that `mvn dependency:tree` usually works properly, but `sbt dependency-tree` often doesn't.  It seems to leave off some dependencies.

Comment: Outdated question, now IDEs import Sbt project also.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Did you try [`make-pom`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/api/sbt/internal/librarymanagement/MakePom.html) from [sbt](https://github.com/sbt/sbt)?

It generates basic POM for the current project at the *./target*. 
To customize generation, you can override `pomExtra`, `pomIncludeRepository` and `pomPostProcess` at the project definition.

Comment: I tried make-pom, I think my IDE only reads pom.xml file to import a project, do I need to create it manually?

Comment: I use `make-pom` to import SBT projects into Netbeans (that supports only Maven- and Ant-based project out of the box). It has always been taking for me just to run `make-pom`, rename produced artifact definition to `pom.xml`, and move it to the project root (last two steps can be automated in SBT with `pomPostProcess`).

Comment: @VasilRemeniuk I'm having some trouble trying to find how to do those two steps, the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html) says it is a `Node => Node` function. Modifying the root [Node](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.xml.Node) and children should be enough to modify the XML, but: how to move the file? Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

There is a very direct way provided by SBT. You can use the below command where your SBT file exixts:

**sbt makePom**

This will generate the .pom file in the target folder you can search that and rename to pom.xml and keep that file in the location and run **mvn clean compile install** to get full out of it.

Answer (score 6):

Vasil's answer is correct, but for Eclipse and IDEA you can generate IDE metadata more directly using plugins.  For IDEA https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea, and for Eclipse https://github.com/musk/SbtEclipsify .