# How to properly combine NetBeans, Scala, and Maven?

Tags: scala, maven, netbeans

I'm trying to create a Maven project in NetBeans, and have NetBeans recognize it as a Scala project and use the Scala plugins, but can't figure this out.

I can combine Scala and Maven without NetBeans.  This is just a matter of getting the pom right, and that works great when run with mvn.  No problem.

I can combine NetBeans and Maven without Scala.  Here, NetBeans is happy to open a Scala project that uses Maven, but it just sees it as a generic Maven project and won't actually load all the Scala plugins, so I get no features beyond syntax highlighting.

I can combine NetBeans and Scala without Maven.  For example, when creating a new Scala project, the project properly loads with the Scala plugins enabled, and I get all the goodies, but it's using Ant and I can't figure out how to get it to recognize Maven after defining a pom.

Somehow, I want to create/open a Scala Maven project in NetBeans and have it recognize it as a Scala project and use the Scala plugins for NetBeans.  Is this a doable thing?

Comment: You should read this blog: http://blogtrader.net/blog/how_to_setup_dependencies_aware2 It's from Caoyuan Deng, the maintainer of the netbeans scala plugin.

Comment: That seems to have helped, no thanks to my new arch-nemesis Mr Barber.  Statically defining the build.sourceDirectory, rather than letting the scala-maven-plugin find it automatically during the compile phase, seems to have given NetBeans enough info to properly init the Scala plugins.

Comment: @Andrew Barber why that's not a question? I mean how do I setup my maven scala project on netbeans definitively look like a question to me.

Comment: @guillaume please read the information in the close reason. In particular, it is overly broad.

Comment: @JohnSmith you can also generate a pom from sbt with ```sbt make-pom``` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067501/sbt-to-maven-converter

Comment: @AndrewBarber can you reopen this question. I think JohnSmith could reformulate.

Comment: @GuillaumeMassé The question would get reopened *after*, not before.