# Is it possible to use the Scala-Play ecosystem via Maven only? How?

Tags: scala, maven, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I need to develop a Scala-Play application in a very controlled environment where they have Maven established but do not allow any other build tool e.g. sbt. I really want sbt of course but I can't have it here. Therefore my question, is it possible to use Maven only to setup a Scala - Play application? note I do not want to use Java i.e. productivity.

I have used Scala - Play and I am very accustomed to the Play sbt plugin that setups every nicely for activator etc but unfortunately I do not enjoy that choice here ... however, I can do anything with Maven.

Needless to say I have tried to setup SBT and Activator locally to fetch dependencies tunneling via the existing Nexus Maven without success. The nexus instance doesn't have an ivy2 repository and I am not allowed to create one.

Comment: I have no experience to share on this, but couldn't you use a POM generator for sbt and make the build process happy that way ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067501/sbt-to-maven-converter

Comment: I don't think Maven is capable of providing the incremental Scala compilation (i.e. only recompiling changed files and its dependents). So brace yourself for long compile times if you don't use SBT.

Comment: It's capable - http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_incremental.html, unfortunately, it's in maintenance mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is Play Maven plugin (though it still in beta):
https://github.com/play2-maven-plugin/play2-maven-plugin

I did not use it, but I did few Play modules that depend on Play and build completely in Maven. I use Play from the Maven central repository. Hope this will help you.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-java_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${play.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-cache_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${play.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-json_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${play.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```