# Combining different repositories as a single maven project

Tags: maven, github, intellij-idea, sbt, maven-2

I have few standalone projects which are built in sbt and few are in maven.
These projects are available in github as seperate repositories. 
Now the task is to keep all these projects into a single repository.

My plan is to keep all these projects as different packages into a single maven project and store this into a single repo. I am using IntelliJ as IDE.
How can I achieve this? Or is there any easy way to achieve this, other than just copying all repos into a single one?
Can we keep both sbt build and maven build file together in one project or do we need to migrate all the sbt builds to maven?

Any leads appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine them into a single Maven repository then obviously you will need to convert Sbt projects into a Maven ones. To convert you may consider using [makePom](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/api/sbt/internal/librarymanagement/MakePom.html) from SBT. See also [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5067695/2000323).

> Can we keep both sbt build and maven build file together in one project or do we need to migrate all the sbt builds to maven?

You can. In IDE then you will need to choose if you would like to open such project (module) as a [Maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start) or [SBT](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sbt-support.html#import_sbt) based.